# Logging Spring REST APIs

Tags: java, spring, logging, filter, interceptor

I have custom Filter and I want to log  body from request.
But when I use `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and try to call `getContentAsByteArray()` I always get an empty array.

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

       log.info(getRequestData(requestToCache));
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public static String getRequestData(final HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String payload = null;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeRequest(request, ContentCachingRequestWrapper.class);
        if (wrapper != null) {
            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                payload = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
            }
        }
        return payload;
    }
  }
```

I also tried create `Interceptor`, but had the same problem.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this not caused by the fact you're creating a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` before your call to `getRequestData`, where it's creating another `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`? I suspect because it reads the body when you create the first `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` that it can't re-read from the buffer when creating  the second and therefore the body is null/empty. You could always pass the first `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` into your method rather than creating a second instance.

Comment: I also used it once and had the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the existing spring implementation by just registering this bean in a `@Configuration` annotated class:

```
@Bean
public static Filter requestLoggingFilter() {
    final CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    loggingFilter.setMaxPayloadLength(512);

    return loggingFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I'd recommend going with NiVer's answer, I've been looking into why this issue occurs and I can finally give you an answer.

When you create a new `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`, the internal `ByteArrayOutputStream` is initialized but **no data is copied to it**. The body is only written to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` when you call `getParameter`, `getParameterMap()`, `getParameterNames()` or `getParameterValues(String name)` methods, and even then the data is only copied if the content type contains `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I saw empty array and could`t understand why. Thank you for help!